# User sessions are not ended

Tags: ssh, fedora, systemd

I recently noticed, that there are around **60 sessions** opened on all of my hosts. (`loginctl list-sessions`)

Details showing up that these sessions are coming from **Zabbix Monitoring** which is periodically running some scripts to generate statistics.

I could destroy them with `loginctl terminate-session`. After 24 hours, there are already some sessions again. I then started monitoring these sessions. See this graph:

[image: sessions count]

Details of a session:

```
loginctl show-session c96339
Id=c96339
User=0
Name=root
Timestamp=Thu 2017-05-04 03:38:28 CEST
TimestampMonotonic=2551128480813
VTNr=0
Remote=no
RemoteUser=zabbix
Service=sudo
Scope=session-c96339.scope
Leader=14070
Audit=0
Type=unspecified
Class=background
Active=yes
State=closing
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
```

Sometimes, the server is getting very slow and the **load average** is somewhat over **40**. I have to restart the `systemd-logind` service. After that, everything is ok again.

Does anyone have an idea why I have to restart that service regularly and why the sessions are not automatically destroyed?

**System:**

Fedora 24 (x86_64)

Kernel: 4.9.12-100.fc24.x86_64

Zabbix Agent: zabbix-agent-3.0.7-1.fc24.x86_64

Systemd: systemd-229-18.fc24.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at `ClientAliveInterval` setting in `sshd_config` on the server side. With a value different from 0, this should close disconnected sessions after a given amount of time. (see also `ClientAliveCountMax`)

`man sshd_config` will give you more informations about these settings.

Comment: Thank you, both options were indeed set to 0 (default). I have set it now and check again in a few days.

Comment: bit counterintuitive: by enabling keepalive the connection no longer stays alive.

Comment: @jiggunjer said another way, by enabling "ssh internal keepalive", dead sessions don't stay unnoticed anymore.